# Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery"

Tags: sql-server, powershell, exception

When I attempt to insert new data in database via PowerShell, it works.

However, if the data is already in database, I get exception.

Someone had similar problem, [Catch exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316313/catch-exception-calling-executenonquery), but I believe I am using the correct SQL statement in my PowerShell code, where I say `SELECT 1`

```
$SQL_insert = "BEGIN
              IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM [dbo].[Group_Stats]
                             WHERE Date_of_Record = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                             AND [Group] = '$group')
              BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Group_Stats] ([Date_of_Record], [Group], [Windows_SEP_11],[Mac_SEP_11],[Windows_SEP_12],[Mac_SEP_12])
                  VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), REPLACE ('$group', 'My Company\', ''), $win_sep_11, $mac_sep_11, $win_sep_12, $mac_sep_12)
              END
          END"
```

Exception

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Group_Stats'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Group_Stats'.
```

And this is the database

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying for the untrimmed group name, but when you insert, you call `REPLACE()` to trim "My Company" off `$group`. You should instead trim the `$group` first, then query and insert without calling `REPLACE()`.